# Help with proof of this set being countable?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

For the set $\{x + y\sqrt{3} : x,y \in \Bbb{Q}\}$, I want to show it's countable. It's obviously not empty, and it's not finite as x,y are rationals.

To show it's a bijection and therefore countable I'm trying to argue that if x,y are rational then they each have their own bijection .

If $\phi$ is the bijection for x and $\psi$ for y, with $\phi(1) = x$, then I want to argue that we can define a $\Gamma$ s.t $\Gamma (1) = (\phi(1), \psi(1)), \Gamma(2) = (\phi(1), \psi(2))$ etc.

Does this accurately or concretely illustrate that $\Gamma$ is the bijective function for the set? If not what do I need to do to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really defined $\Gamma$. You may notice that each element of the given set (say, $A$) is associated with a pair of rational numbers, so you may try and define a function $f:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to A$ by
$$f(x,y)=x+y\sqrt{3}$$
This is clearly a surjective map, so the cardinality of $A$ cannot be larger than
the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, which is $\aleph_0$. In fact, $f$ is also injective, because of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$. Thus $f$ is actually a bijection.